# O tipo está definido numa assemblagem que não está referenciada

Tags: c#, visual-studio, referência, class-library

Tenho um projecto chamado `DataLibrary`, a .dll está referenciada noutro projeto meu, mas por alguma razão, na hora de compilar o VS dá-me um erro a dizer que há um tipo que está defenido em `DataLibrary` mas que preciso de adicionar uma referência. Eu tenho a referência, e há muitas (muitas) partes do código em que uso tipos e métodos do `DataLibrary`.

Eu puxei este projeto do source control, de certeza que o erro é por causa disso. Como posso resolver? Já me aconteceu isso antes, com um projeto semelhante, mas o problema ficou resolvido sem ter feito nada a não ser reiniciar o VS (!!) agora já não tive a mesma sorte. Veja em baixo o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A referencia não tem que estar no seu outro servico? O CompaniesService?  A referência que voce esta mostrando é na BusinessServiceImplementation.

Comment: O companies service (e muitos mais) estão nesse projeto cujas referências estão no print. Esses serviços WCF apontam para classes que mexem com a base de dados, é que foram definidas noutro projeto, tudo na mesma solução.

Comment: Certo, mas se você estiver usando a referência diretamente no próprio WCF, vai ter que por a referência diretamente onde tiver chamadas da mesma. Teria como mostrar a linha com o erro e suas referencias?

Comment: Sim, vou colocar isso, mas só amanhã pois já saí do trabalho 

Comment: O erro não me aparece mais...não percebi o que se passou...

Comment: O proprio Nuget não atualizou as referências que estavam faltando ?

Comment: O nuget? a referência era para um dll minha, pensava que o Nuget é para baixar livrarias da net

Comment: Se tiver um repositório próprio configurado, pode-se usar nuget da mesma forma, ele não serve só pra pegar referencias do nuget.org que é apenas um repositório centralizado. Mas pelo visto vc colocou a dll manualmente, realmente é um misterio ter saido o erro XD

Comment: como tinha dito na pergunta, isso aconteceu-me antes e o erro sumiu, agora aconteceu outra vez..tenho mesmo sorte em as coisas se resolverem sozinhas xD

Comment: As vezes é sujeira de cache nas referências, da vários CLEANS e REBUILDS , vai que resolve. Só em fechar e abrir depois de um tempo resolveu, vai que é isso.